# Efficient Job Scheduling Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling

I host a video encoding service. My clients submit some videos to encode. Presently, I encode them in just a FIFO manner. I would like to change it so that every client gets a fare share of my service.

I would like to consider the following factors:
1. FIFO - First to submit the job has higher priority. 
2. If the client submits a large number of videos, I would like to take his priority down.

I have control over the priority of the clients by setting an attribute from the database, but not over each video.
How can I have more control over all the videos and schedule them efficiently?

PS: I can redesign the database if needed.

Comment: Why aren't you using the cloud to simply scale up the number of encoders as needed and down when not needed, then you don't have this problem.

Comment: I am using the AWS cloud, I am running my encoding services on fixed number of ec2 instances (saves cost). The videos that are present need to be encoded offline. I can scale the ec2 instances as needed, but I think at the moment it is not needed as I don't have many clients. But I would like to have an efficient algorithm to schedule tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that's fair to clients: Instead of queueing jobs, queue the clients who submit jobs into a FIFO. As each client reaches the front of the queue, encode their first job, and if that client has more jobs, put that client back in the queue at the end.

Comment: That is smart. But, in the future maybe I would like to have other parameters like video size etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could compute a cost for encoding (based on size and/or quality), and divide it by the age of the request (curent time minus time the request was issued plus some damping constant).
You would then use this score to queue the request in increasing order.

A client queing big requests would have to wait for smaller requests to be processed, but would eventually get a score small enough to be scheduled.